# Create SQL Database from ADO.NET Typed Dataset

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, dataset

I have a DataSet defined and designed in visual studio.

Who knows of a tool to generate tables in SQL Server to match the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an article I found very very helpful in building a class to do just that.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/4929a0a8-0137-45f6-86e8-d11e220048c3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tools that will do it just like that - but you could always use SMO (the SQL Server Management Objects) to read your DataSet's structure and create database tables from that.

Marc